# Python App ouput to syslog server

Tags: python, unix, syslog, system-administration

I'm trying to do some searching on google (looped for every 5 min or so).
When it gets a hit I want it to push the results to a syslog server. I'm very new to python so please forgive the ignorance, I have searched for ages and can't find an answer to my question.

I intend to add multiple queries looking for diffirent results depending on the query results the logevent differs.

```
WARN "possible hit"
CRITICAL "definatly a hit"
etc
```

I would like the output to be for example like:
log type, url, date/time

Below is the code I've been playing with so far. I can search and log to a file but not how I would like to. I'm only getting the formatting for time and the even type, I'm not getting my query results in the log. And i have no idea how to log to a syslog server.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import urllib
import simplejson, logging

query = urllib.urlencode({'q' : 'SEARCHTERMHERE'})
url = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&%s' \ % (query)
search_results = urllib.urlopen(url)
json = simplejson.loads(search_results.read())
results = json['responseData']['results']
for i in results:
  logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', filename='hits.log')
  logging.warning ('Likley hit')
  print i['url']

#!/usr/bin/python
import urllib
import simplejson 
import logging
from logging.handlers import SysLogHandler

query = urllib.urlencode({'q' : 'SEARCHTERMHERE'})
url = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&%s' \
% (query)

search_results = urllib.urlopen(url)
json = simplejson.loads(search_results.read())
results = json['responseData']['results']

for i in results:
  print i['url']
  logger = logging.getLogger()
  logger.addHandler(SysLogHandler(address=('192.168.0.2', 514), facility=LOG_USER, socktype=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
  logger.addHandler(logging.FileHandler("hits.log"))
  logging.warn("likley Hit: " + i['url'])
```

I get :
      File "gog.py", line 18
        logger.addHandler(logging.FileHandler("hits.log"))
         ^
      SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can configure the logging module to output to syslog, see http://docs.python.org/library/logging.handlers.html#sysloghandler

Simple example:

```
from logging.handlers import SysLogHandler
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.addHandler(SysLogHandler('/dev/log'))
logger.addHandler(logging.FileHandler("filename.log"))

logging.warn("Hello world")
```

The above logs to the local syslog using a Unix domain socket. You can also specify a hostname to log to syslog using UDP. See the docs for more info.

Comment: thanks for the quick response, I have seen that but to be honest with you im struggeling to udnerstand it. could you give me an example maybe? I couldnt see how i could get my results into the log and send it to a syslog server

Comment: So you want to log to both a file and to a syslog server? In that case add two handlers.

Comment: thank you for pointing out the SysLogHandler ill take a closer look from there, can you let me know how would i get my results into the log? for instance logging.warn('url')

Comment: this seems to be a bit more useable http://csl.sublevel3.org/py-syslog-win32/ but i still dont understand how i pass myresults to the logs

Comment: The example above puts "Hello world" in my syslog file. What is your scenario, networkwise? Are you on a windows box and want to log messages to a linux/unix syslog? In that case, make sure that the syslog server listens to the default syslog UDP port. Consult the OS documentation for instructions on how to do that.

Comment: ok think ive got the loggin down now but i still dont know how to get my 'url' results into the logs?

Comment: codeape im trying to get the results from (my original post) into the syslog server( remote) from a windows box

Comment: i believe this code will work for the remote syslog but as mentioned im not sure how to get i['url'] results into the logs for   i in results:
  print i['url']

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
syslog = SysLogHandler(address=('x.x.x.x', SYSLOG_UDP_PORT)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(name)s: %(levelname)s %(message)s')
syslog.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(syslog)

Comment: Simply include the URL in the call to ``logging.warn``: ``logging.warn("Likely hit: " + i["url"])``

Comment: ARRr i was trying that earlier but could get the syntx correct i guess

Comment: logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.addHandler(SysLogHandler(address = 'x.x.x.x'))
logger.addHandler(logging.FileHandler("hits.log"))
logging.warn("likley Hit: " + i['url'])

Comment: does this work for you 
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.addHandler(SysLogHandler(address=('192.168.0.2', 514))
logger.addHandler(logging.FileHandler("hits.log"))
logging.warn("likley Hit: " + i['url'])

Comment: YAY got it logging but its only logging the last line from the results any idea?

Comment: well its kinda working now, loging but not loging as expected

Comment: Your three lines of logging setup code should not be inside the loop. Move it outside the loop so it's only executed once.