# Thread randomly stops in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I've been playing along with threads in Python, and I came across something interesting with the following code:

```
import time
import threading

class Update(threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.stop_event = threading.Event()

  def join(self, timeout=None):
    self.stop_event.set()
    threading.Thread.join(self, timeout)

  def run(self):
    while not self.stop_event.isSet():
      print("test")

thread = Update()
thread.start()
```

This code randomly stops even if I don't call the **join()** method. As a result, I get different outputs like these:

```
test@debian:~/$ python3 test.py
test
test
test
test
test@debian:~/$ python3 test.py
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test@debian:~/$ python3 test.py
test
test
```

Why is this code randomly stopping? I thought that only by setting **stop_event** this thread would stop.

Comment: Please note that print is not thread-safe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18234469/python-multithreaded-print-statements-delayed-until-all-threads-complete-executi

Comment: @JoãoPinto: That question isn't actually about thread-safety. It doesn't even *use* any threads; it forks a bunch of processes instead, and I don't think the processes had anything to do with the problem.

Comment: Comments are not answers, my comment is provided in the context that the user is attempting to debug a multi-threaded application using prints to stdout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already got the essential answer, but there's a detail you need to be aware of:  when the main program ends, as part of shutdown processing Python calls `.join()` on all non-daemon threads created by the `threading` module.  You overrode `.join()`, so Python calls *your* `.join()`.  That in turn sets the event, and so your `.run()` method exits silently.

Comment: So *that's* why the non-daemon thread isn't blocking the shutdown. It makes sense; Python needs to wait for non-daemon threads to finish, so it calls the method specifically designed to wait for a thread to finish.

Comment: Also, it's easy to show that this is what happens - add a print statement to the join method and you'll see that the join method gets called.

Answer (score 2):

When the *main* thread ends the program ends.

The number of times that the thread loops before the main one stops is fairly arbitrary. (up to the OS to schedule)

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects) say all non-daemon threads need to end before the program ends.

Comment: @user2357112 Yes I was just looking for proof that garbage collection closed the thread when the program ends but it seems that garbage collection has nothing to do with it and TimPeters has provided the correct answer to how the thread is closed.