# Python's ProcessPoolExecutor is giving output of print and return statement in reverse order

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I was practicing using multiprocessing in Python, so I came across `concurrent.futures` module. I tried running the following code:

```
import concurrent.futures
import time


def do_something(seconds):
    print(f'Sleeping {seconds} second(s)...')
    time.sleep(seconds)
    return f'Done Sleeping for {seconds} second(s)'

def main():

    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        results = [executor.submit(do_something, 1.5) for _ in range(2)]

        for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(results):
            print(f.result())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.perf_counter()
    main()
    finish = time.perf_counter()
    print(f'Finished in {round(finish-start, 2)} second(s)')
```

I should expect something like the following as output:

```
Sleeping 1.5 second(s)...
Sleeping 1.5 second(s)...
Done Sleeping for 1.5 second(s)
Done Sleeping for 1.5 second(s)
Finished in 1.5 second(s)
```

But, I got:

```
Done Sleeping for 1.5 second(s)
Done Sleeping for 1.5 second(s)
Sleeping 1.5 second(s)...
Sleeping 1.5 second(s)...
Finished in 1.83 second(s)
```

Isn't it weird that the return statement is coming before the print statement?
Here is the exact snip:
[sublime_snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVz23.png)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This may have to do with standard out buffering. Try passing `flush=True` in your print statement like:

```
print(f'Sleeping {seconds} second(s)...', flush=True)
```

You can see this is a pretty common issue with multiprocessed printing: [Python multithreaded print statements delayed until all threads complete execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18234469/python-multithreaded-print-statements-delayed-until-all-threads-complete-executi)