# popen write stdout to file and shell with background process

Tags: python, logging, subprocess, popen

I am using `Popen` to start a background process and I am writing the stdout and stderr to a file:

```
with open("log.log", "w+", buffering=1) as out:
    p = subprocess.Popen(["run", "cmd"], stdout=out, stderr=out, bufsize=1)
```

Is it possible to also display stdout and stderr in shell (i.e., on screen)?

I am aware that I could use a `PIPE` for it, but then my code would block for execution of `Popen`.

Comment: Have you seen this question and answers to it? https://stackoverflow.com/q/803265/4440387

Comment: This and similar solutions are using PIPE, but then I would need to iterate over it in my code, which would block other execution.

Comment: you can shuffle display off to a thread, which you may want to do anyways to serialize output from multiple sources (via a [queue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57809668/4541045)?)